# asynchronous request objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am developing a sms App for my client. so far i have put down this plan in place.

1)The app keeps polling the server with an asynchronous request so that it does not interfere with the user interface.

2) for sending sms i am currently using synchronous request , depending on the reply from server i have do various things. i am showing the  spinning circle and make the user wait until i get the response from server.

my client has problem with point 2.

The client says as soon as the send sms button is clicked it has to go back to the homescreen and should be able to navigate to any screen and do all other things that the app offers. i could have used async request , but i am not sure how to handle the responses from the server when i am on different view controller other than the one request is called from.

Can somebody help me on this.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you put the sending logic in the class that's doing the polling? That way they can both run in the background while the user navigates through the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classic way of handling the response of an asynchronous action is either using delegation or notifications. **Do not use a singleton. This breaks modularity and decoupling of different view controllers**.

#### Roadmap of how to handle asynchronous actions

1. Register for the response of the asynchronous actions. This can be setting the delegate of the requesting object e.g. `NSURLConnection` to the view controller, which is typically `self` in this context. The othe possibility is that you register for the notification which is fired by the requesting object if things have happend e.g. when a download is finished or an error occurred.
2. Implement the delegate methods or the notifications to update your model and/or your user interface. *Be aware that updating the UI has to happen on your main thread.*
3. Start the asynchronous action. What happens in the background is that a separate thread is spawned or an operation is dispatched using GCD. These are implementation details and do not bother you.
4. Wait for the answer, which will result in one of your implemented methods to be executed which you then use to update what has changed.

#### Difference between notifications and delegates

The two differences between delegates and notifications is that delegate is a one-to-one connection between the delegate and the delegating object. Notifications are posted application wide and can be observed by as many objects as needed creating a one-to-many connection. Think about this as a broadcast. The second main difference is that delegation can be used to transfer information back from the delegate to the delegating object. Meaning that the delegating object asks the delegate for certain information. Typical example would be the data source of an `UITableView`. Notifications however are a one way street. The information flows from the posting object to the observing objects. This makes sense because think about the situation where you would have more than one observer and each would give feedback to the posting objects. Which one would be the right one?

In your case you would have to look up the delegate methods of the asynchronous HTTP request object and implement them accordingly.

Comment: thank you soo much for your suggestion , i used delegation and it worked pretty well. however i have another problem. the above answer to my question makes me feel you can answer my next problem. Please check out my next question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try ASIHTTpRequest , It has Sync an Async request

If you using Async request , you can do anything after you press a button to do a request .

[Check this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

Answer (score -1):

The solution depends on the response processing.... if you are just showing user that the sms sending is failed/successful than you can do it in any general utility class that shows alert.. but for this you have to create the singletone instance of your connection class so delegate(class itself) don't die when the response comes back.......

Comment: @user698952 . Well, when the user sends the sms , depending on the resonse from the server i have to display a different view controller and some times just a plain sms sent alertview.

Comment: I am afraid you are misusing the term _singleton_. A singleton is an object of one class that is shared among all the application. For example [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] is a singleton or [UIApplication sharedApplication] is a singleton, because **there is only one object**. In your case you can have more than one asynchronous HTTP request in the application, so **this is not a singleton**.

Comment: Also the reasoning about why you would need a singleton is wrong. The delegate object is not release because it is usually this delegate object that owns (retains) the object calling the delegate. Think of `UITableView`: The tableViewController retains the `UITableView` and that is why the data source (a delegate) is always there if the tableView calls it. If the controller goes away it also releases the tableView, so no situation can arise in which the delegate is deallocated before the tableView!

Comment: @GorillaPatch : The behavior of UITableView and delegate methods of asynchonous connection should not be compared.... because in asynchronous connection... delegates would be call in between, in future, we are never sure when they will be called.... And in the case @Rajashekar wants to have delegation methods invoked even after the viewcontroller changes... thats why connections delegate object must be live even after the calling viewcontroller dies .... or else he would not be able to get the response..

Answer (score -1):

For this we need to keep track of currentViewController ....... we can do this by creating a reference ........ `id currentViewController` in `appDelegate(with setter/getters)`.......... so it could be accessible in everywhere application........

its referred object should be changed each time when user changes the viewController.... that will help us to know on which viewController user is currently working.

than when the singeltone class of connection finished its response loading we can use this `currentViewController with your desired viewController.`

I am not sure how you are using different view controller....... pushing it/ presenting it or adding its view.....

Comment: @user698952 so u think i should use singleton class(which has ASI-HTTP-AsynRequest) with keeping track of viewcontroller   OR should i consider singleton class(which has ASI-HTTP-AsynRequest) with adding viewcontroller to the appdelegate window depending on the response, any idea...

Comment: singleton for the class which has delegation of NSURLConnection class... so that when you move from one viewcontroller to other ... you dont release this class ....... otherwise it will fail to locate its delegation.......... and for currentViewController(which helps us in tracking the current viewcontroller) we need to make it property in appDelegate so it could be accessible by all the viewControllers ..... also i am still not sure which kind of viewcontroller replacement mech. you are using.......

Comment: @user698952 rightnow i am not using any viewcontroller replacement mech, in my previous apps if i need a viewcontroller popup regardless of any viewcontroller that is on top- i add a view controller to the appdelegate window and remove it when done.

Comment: @user698952 i have been doing some reading since my earlier post and though i should use ASI-HTTP-AsynRequest since its more robost that nsurlconnection and it offers lot more options. i will try to use singleton class with ASI-HTTP-AsynReques delegate methods and see what happens. do u think its a nice idea.

Comment: @Rajashekar yes , the basic idea behind this discussion is that we need to have a live object which can be used even after we change the view controller/or release it.....  @GorillaPatch is suggesting us a normal way to use it(it can be used only when we are still waiting for response, but we are not..).... I hope you got my idea about use of singleton.... also for this response processing we should user some method that is written in appDelegate... that will reduce duplicate code for handling this particular response.... Thanks